# Bootstrap + Affix : affixed menu jumps off screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to set up a simple example with Bootstrap's *affix.js*.

However, the problem is that the item which I am trying to have sticky jumps off the screen with a negative `top` as soon as it switches from `affix-top` to `affix`.  And it never recovers from there.

I set up a small jsfiddle, which illustrates the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/mjg12uep/6/

I have done it successfully on another project, but can't for the heck of it figure out what is going on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When playing around a little bit more, I realized that it works when I add `position: relative` to `.affix-top`. I suppose without that, the javascript was not sure where to *"anchor"* the element, and pushed it off screen. I have updated the fiddle accordingly.